# How to answer this question : List employees who were hired in 1986

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, where-clause

I am working on something and this my last thing I need to do. I have tried everything from

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date 
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date LIKE '1986%';
```

I keep getting this error message.

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883 Character: 73

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal because `hire_date` is certainly a DATE data type while the operator `Like` applies only for Strings data types. What you can do is extract the date directly: `Where DATEPART(year, hire_date) = '1986'`

Answer (score 4):

It is almost never a good idea to treat a date-like datatype as a string (although some RDBMS support it).

Most RDBMS support standard sql function `extract()`. You seem to be using postgresql, which is no exception, so:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date 
FROM employees
WHERE extract(year from hire_date) = 1986
```

Answer (score 3):

You should phrase this using date comparisons:

```
where hire_date >= '1986-01-01' and
      hire_date < '1987-01-01'
```

Why should you use direct comparisons?  Three reasons:

- This allows the use of indexes to optimize the query.
- This allows the use of partitions.
- The optimizer has more information.

In general, functions on columns prevent all these means of optimization, as does type conversion.

You specifically should not be using `LIKE`.  That is a string function.  You want to use date functions and operators on dates.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date LIKE '1986-%-%';
This will work

Comment: This fiddle seems to say it does not work in PostgreSQL 9.6: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2195f4/1